# stop html elements onclick propogation

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

My HTML code is like this:

```
    <div id="divAutoPlay" onclick="autoPlay(0);">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:;" onClick="autoPlay(3);">3 Times</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;" onClick="autoPlay(5);">5 Times</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;" onClick="autoPlay(10);">10 Times</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
```

`ul` is a popup coming on `div` hover to select auto times, and if clicked `div` itself (on progress popup don't show up) auto play stops.

```
    function autoPlay(playCount){
        if(autoPlayCount>0)
           autoPlayCount=playCount;
        else if(playCount>0){
           setTimeout(function(){
               autoPlayCount=playCount;
               $('#divPlay').click();
           }, 2000);
        }
        // don't know how to add stopPropogation effectively
        //event.stopPropagation();
        // commented codes doesn't worked
        /*            
        if (event.stopImmediatePropagation){
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }else if(window.event){
            window.event.cancelBubble=true;
        }
        */
        // for this also changed function definition to pass 'event' onClick="autoPlay(event,10);"
    }
```

The problem is that if I clicked n times on `li`, the `onclick` on `div` is also fired,  making the playback stop.

Comment: Where is id 'divPlay'?

Comment: some arun had replied for my question, but it deleted before my comment(dont know why, his solution is to pass event as last argument). it worked and now i got the real problem. so i tried to log all. actually there is 2 more calls coming to 'autoPlay' one after 3-5 msec (which is stopped by his solution) and one after 2000 msec (which i have no idea from where its coming). i suspend $('#divPlay').click(); on setTimeout. does in some way or another that may happen ?.

Comment: @MShahzadKhan divPlay is outside divAutoPlay. i suspend $('#divPlay').click(); on setTimeout becouse thats the thing execute after 2000 msec and log shows as the call come after 2003-2005 msec. $('#divPlay').click(); contains only logic to start play, nothing else. any clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the li elements are inside div, there's no way you can click only on li. Instead you can see which element was clicked using
[event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

Then write a condition checking whether the target is div or li.

Comment: i need to accept values from both div and li. what i need is to stop immediate unexpected calling. one thing i can do is with time. but my code fools me on that too :-(

Answer (score 1):

Try returning false from your `onClick`. This will stop the propagation:

```
<div id="divAutoPlay" onclick="autoPlay(0);">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:;" onClick="autoPlay(3); return false;">3 Times</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;" onClick="autoPlay(5); return false;">5 Times</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;" onClick="autoPlay(10); return false;">10 Times</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```